# https to http 301 redirect via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect all the https url to http. As my new server doesn't have ssl enabled.

So Far I tried following but none of them worked.'

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301] 

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: It not redirecting https to http, instead it is giving "Moved Permanently" to http urls

Comment: You must have some other rule overwriting this one, because this IS working. Of course you'll get a security alert from most browsers (no https certificate) but the redirect is properly set : https://www.darma.fr/test/test.html Besides, "Moved Permanently" = 301 which is what you're looking for, are you aware of that?