# HTTPS to HTTP redirect via .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, https

I have a website hosted on a GoDaddy wordpress hosting.  We had an SSL, but not longer have the SSL.  Google archive some pages with the SSL so I just want to redirect https requests to the http version of the sit.e  I have access to the .htaccess file so I figured that was the best way to do it.

I have been searching around and tried tons of different .htaccess redirects, but none of them are working.  Including this [https to http 301 redirect via htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12226795/https-to-http-301-redirect-via-htaccess).  I know the htaccess is functioning because wordpress is working and I added a few test redirects to it and they worked as well.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress has its own redirect procedure.

Check in the General Settings of you WP Panel for the WordPress Address and the Site Address fields. Make sure they both are non ssl absolute paths.

Another thing to check is on the wp-config.php

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
```

That could have been added by another plugin. Remove it or make it false.

One last thing you could try (not the best option) is to ask google to remove those specific links, [here's a reference](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2010/03/url-removal-explained-part-i-urls.html) for that.

I hope this helps.

Comment: The general settings are correct.  The site is working great in general.  Google just has the https version of the site archive.  I just want to add a 301 redirect if a user hits the site via the https.  I will request from Google, but in the mean time I just need to redirect https references to http  .

Comment: Take a look at your .htaccess, there may be another rule overwriting your redirect rule

Comment: There isn't anything in the .htaccess besides the typical wordpress stuff. and that rule from above http://pastebin.com/H2Fe1khP

Comment: Is that your actual htaccess file?

Comment: Yes with the exception of removed the acutal domain and replaced with domain.com

Comment: You could try adding a port condition: `RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443` and change the domain url to server constants `RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]`

Comment: One thing, super important. You need to enclose your code on `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>...rules... </IfModule>` I should have seen that earlier.

Comment: I added that, but not working.  I'm getting thiw now domiain uses an unsupported protocol.
ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of ideas.